# Yolov8 object detection model visualization in Netron

Tags: deep-learning, python, pytorch, object-detection, yolo

I trained a YOLOv8 nano detection model with `imgsz=320` and 36 classes. When I conver it to ONNX, I get the following message:

```
PyTorch: starting from 'best.pt' with input shape (1, 3, 320, 320) BCHW and output shape(s) (1, 40, 2100) (5.9 MB)
```

What is the rational behind output of `(1, 40, 2100)`? I have 36 classes, so why we see the number 40 here? What is that 2100? And how are these related to the input size?

I see this output when I try to visualize with Netron:

[image]